# can i count the next day as previous day?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to count 6am-12:30am(next day) as one date.
For some reason I cannot pull this data from the next day in for the previous day.
Is this possible?

```
(CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(ITD.TRAN_DATE,'HH24MI')>='0600' THEN TO_CHAR(ITD.TRAN_DATE,'HHAM')
WHEN TO_CHAR(TRUNC(ITD.TRAN_DATE+1),'HH24MI')<='0030' THEN TO_CHAR(ITD.TRAN_DATE,'HHAM')
END)
```

I am using this case statement to have everything until 12:30am the next day to count as the previous day.  It will not work when I set a date parameter.

Comment: Show some sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is **yes**.

The pseudo-code is:

```
IF (TRAN_TIME <= 00:30 AND TRAN_DATE = TODAY + 1) OR
   (TRAN_TIME >= 06:00 AND TRAN_DATE = TODAY) 
THEN ...
```

What you are currently doing, is taking the existing date, and adding one to it, before comparing the times, and that won't return what you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Use an `INTERVAL` data type to add an offset to a date:

```
SELECT *
FROM   itd
WHERE  ITD.TRAN_DATE
         BETWEEN TRUNC( :date_to_match ) + INTERVAL '00 06:00' DAY TO MINUTE
         AND     TRUNC( :date_to_match ) + INTERVAL '01 12:30' DAY TO MINUTE;
```